# Piping ReadableStream to child process stdin

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

I'm trying to spawn ghostscript using a nodejs child process, I want to pass a ReadableStream as stdin. Seems like ghostscript does not pick up my input, why is that? I know I could do all of this sync etc. but I want to keep the memory footprint as small as possible. I need to process the stdout stream from ghostscript even more in a later step.

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const fs = require('fs')

const params = [
  '-q',
  '-dQUIET',
  '-dSAFER',
  '-dBATCH',
  '-dNOPAUSE',
  '-dNOPROMPT',
  '-dMaxBitmap=500000000',
  '-dAlignToPixels=0',
  '-dGridFitTT=2',
  '-sDEVICE=pngalpha',
  '-dTextAlphaBits=4',
  '-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4',
  '-sOutputFile=%stdout', //output to stdout
  '-' // get input from stdin
]

const stream = var readStream = fs.createReadStream('myfile.eps')
const gs = spawn('gs', params)
stream.pipe(gs.stdin)

ls.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
ls.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});
ls.on("close", (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```